# What is the maximum box size?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

One starts out with 20 spaces in one's Monster Box. Space can be increased by five by spending a Magic Stone. Is there a limit to the size to which one may upgrade one's Monster Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes there is a limit, it currently has a maximum box size is 1500.

That would take 296 magic stones to completely fill as of now, the size limit could change in a later patch as it already has several times since 2013 where the box size limit was 500.

---

The latest patch notes we have of this are:

> Version 7.0.1 (Aug 06, 2014)
>
> ◇ ◆ Ver7.0.1 update information ◆ ◇
>   ▽ new additional features
>   ◆ Revised the contents of the Terms of Use
>   ◆ **The increase in 1500 monster BOX**
>   ◆ Re-adjust the color of the drop
>
> ▽ bug fixes
>   ◆ bug fixes
>   ◆ Other, fine brush up
>   ※ For more information, please check the "Events / Update Information" within the app than "other".

So we can concluded that there is a maximum box size of 1500.

---

[Source](http://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/app/puzzle-dragons//)

Comment: I read that too, but I guess I was hoping for a more official source. I don't know how reliable that poster is.

Answer (score 0):

If [the App Annie web-site](http://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/app/puzzle-dragons-english/) reports/archives accurately, and the information is as simple as it seems, the maximum box size must be 1100.

> Version 6.5.2 (Jul 10, 2014)
>
> Ver. 6.5.2 Update Details
>
> New Features:
>   [...]
>   -Maximum Monster Box size has been raised by 100

[...]

> Version 6.1.0 (Nov 14, 2013)
>
> New Features:
>   [...]
>   - The Monster Box maximum size has been increased from 700 to 1,000"

The site includes the most recent version, so overall, it is up to date.

Deeper searching reveals [one source](http://www.puzzleanddragonsnews.com/category/updates/page/4) that claims 1500. It seems that [this](http://www.appannie.com/apps/ios/app/puzzle-dragons/) pertains to the Japanese version:

> Version 7.0.1 (Aug 06, 2014)
>
> ◇ ◆ Ver7.0.1 update information ◆ ◇
>   [...]
>   ◆ The increase in 1500 monster BOX

There is no mention of a version 7.0.1 of the English version, but the English version numbering is past 7.0.1 now, leaving a possibility that 1500 maximum Monster Box capacity is now the case for the English version too.

Comment: I confirm, it's 1500. I can confirm because I hit the limit : )